# Clarification on a cycle parity proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Prove that cycle $(a_1a_2...a_k)$ is even $\iff$ $k$ is odd.

This makes intuitive sense because $(a_1a_2a_3...a_k)=(a_1a_k)(a_1a_{k-1})...(a_1a_3)(a_1a_2)$ which will be an even number of transpositions when $k$ is odd, and odd number when $k$ is even. I am hoping for something slightly more rigorous, perhaps using the definition of an orbit of $S_n$.

Comment: That's actually exactly how I would have done it. We know that every cycle can be written as the product of two cycles. This means we need the elements in $\{a_{2}, ..., a_{k}\}$ to be mapped bijectively to $\{a_{1}, a_{i} \}$ to get $(a_{1}a_{i})$. I would consider this mapping formal and rigorous, rather than simply intuitive. I'm not familiar enough with orbits to comment on them.